# Distributing balls to baskets with limited size

Tags: java, algorithm, combinatorics

I've been trying to find a solution to this problem for a few hours now: I have *L* balls and *n* baskets labelled X1, X2, ... Xn  , and each container can hold *LXn* balls. Now I want to calculate the number of ways I can distribute those *L* balls into the baskets.

**An example:**

There are 3 baskets X1, X2 and X3, the capacity of X1 and X3 is *2 balls*, X2 has a capacity of *3 balls*. Now *5 balls* are distributed into those baskets:

X1 X2 X3

0  3  2
1  2  2
1  3  1
2  1  2
2  2  1
2  3  0

I want to know how many ways there are to distribute the balls with given values.

**The mathematical solution:**

p_n(x) = x^0 + x^1 + .. + x^(LXn)
P(x) = p_1(x) * ... * p_N(x)

The key is that the coefficient before *x^L* (see next equation) indicates the number of ways to distribute the given *L* balls into the *n* baskets.

With the example above this would result in
P(x) = (1+x+x^2) * (1+x+x^2+x^3) * (1+x+x^2) = 1 + 3x + 6x^2 + 8x^3 + 8x^4 + 6x^5 + 3x^6 + x^7
So for *L=5* it reads *6 different arrangements*

*(Source: http://narkive.com/9a0CvErb.2 (german))*

**Now for my actual question:** Are there ways of doing this, or something similar, in java?

Thanks!

Comment: You want the number of solutions or all possible solutions? The latter is quite more difficult to program.

Comment: @cricket_007 I want the number of solutions, like how the mathematical solution works. My problem is 'converting' this to java code..

Comment: It seems like a dynamic programming problem. I'd probably go about it backwards. In your example, the nth bucket has its capacity of possibilities, the balls in the other n-1 buckets are reliant upon your remaining L value after placing balls in bucket n.

Comment: If you want to go with the solution via polynomials you need a method to multiply two polynomials. You can represent a polynomial as vector of coefficients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach of "creating polynomials"  explained in the link creates a polynomial for each basket and multiples them.

You can represent a polynomial as vector of coefficients, so that `p[i]` is the coefficient for term of degree `i`. A polynomial for a basket with capacity `n` is a polynomial of length `n + 1` with all coefficients equal to 1.

You need a way to multiply polynomials, which you can implement as pairwise multiplication and addition in two nested loops over the terms of the two polynomials.

Finally, the desired number for `m` balls is `p[m]` of the resulting polynomial.

Here's a quick Java implementation. (Disclaimer: I'm not good at all with Java. This code compiles and runs in an online compiler, but probably isn't very Java-esque.)

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main
{
    static int[] basket(int n)
    {
        int[] p = new int[++n];

        while (n-- > 0) p[n] = 1;
        return p;
    }

    static int[] mult(int[] p, int[] q)
    {
        int[] r = new int[p.length + q.length - 1];

        for (int i = 0; i < p.length; ++i) {
            for(int j = 0; j < q.length; ++j) {
                r[i + j] += p[i] * q[j];
            } 
        }

        return r;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] res = basket(0);

        res = mult(res, basket(2));
        res = mult(res, basket(3));
        res = mult(res, basket(2));

        System.out.println(res[5]);
    }
}
```

This snippet implements your example of distributing 5 balls into baskets of size 2, 3, and 2. The starting polynomial `basket(0)` is just the constant 1 and is a neutral element for polynomial multiplication.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for your answer! I think I'll be able to pull this off now, you explained it perfectly.